# Angularjs organizational chart directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Is there any Angularjs Organizational chart directive for wesnolte/jOrgChart or similar chart?

Answer (score 0):

There is one nice way doing it using the Google chart directive. Please see here for implementation details at plunker:

[Plunker Demo Link](http://embed.plnkr.co/OL7ox3/)

Comment: Hi Imran, Sorry I forgot to mention that I do not want to go for Google charts due to some reasons my management is not preferring to it. It would be nice if you can refer some d3 code preferably with Angularjs directive on top of it or using any other open source javascript libraries with Angularjs directives over it. I should be able to replace the rectangles with custom images or icons too. As of now I have come across css3 Html family charts and trying to build angularjs directive with that. If you can direct me to any  such existing directive that would be nice.